# preg_replace &nbsp; turns into number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to extract only the date part out from "string 2015-08-20".

```
$original = "string&nbsp;2015-08-20";

// Trying to remove all but numbers and dashes
$date = preg_replace("#[^0-9-]#iu", '', $original);
// Expecting "2015-08-20"
echo $date;
// But ends up with "1602015-08-20"
```

Why do I get "160" in front of my string?

Comment: `$date = preg_replace("#^.*?;#", '', $original);`

Comment: [**norepro**](https://3v4l.org/FiIUe)

Answer (score 1):

You should really do this the other way round. Search for a datestring, rather than trying to remove everything that isn't a datestring.

This will make the code much more resistant to the unexpected (like a digit being in `$original` that isn't part of a datestring).

```
$original = "string&nbsp;2015-08-20";
preg_match('#\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}#', $original, $matches);

# string(10) "2015-08-20"
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `160` probably because in the string that you're handling the non-breaking space is not expressed in the `&nbsp;` format but in the `&#160;` format. Considering that with your regex you replace all the characters that are not numbers or hypens, in the string `string&#160;2015-08-20` it keeps the `160`, so the result is `1602015-08-20`.
This is the exact situation that Phylogenesis describes and solves in his answer.

Here's a more concise solution:

```
$original = "string&#160;2015-08-20";
$date = preg_replace("#^.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$#", "$1", $original);
```

It replaces the string with only the content of the group, that is exactly the date part.